# Range search in Zillow

Tags: algorithm, computer-vision

How does the range search work for the Zillow ? When we draw a region on the map using the "Draw a custom region" tool in zillow website, how does it detect the houses in that region?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Every house in the database would have a location information, e.g. longitude and latitude. You'll then need to use a spatial data structure to index that information, typically a [R-tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-tree). The spatial index allows you to query records within some region, just like a B-Tree allows you to make normal range queries.